# How to count on Check all that apply options?

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, tableau-desktop

I have a survey which contains several Check all that apply questions. I am using Tableau to do visualization but I failed to split the data into different columns due to the limitation of Tableau Desktop(Seems you need to use Tableau Prep). So I have been thinking about using python to get this done, the table is like this:

```
Q: Which would you like to know more about? (select all that apply)

id    answer   
001   A; B; C
002   A
003   B; C
004   A; C

So, I'd like to get the result like this:

Answer   Count
 A        3
 B        2
 C        3
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are visualizing survey data, especially if using Tableau for survey data, II strongly recommend seeing the following site https://www.datarevelations.com/visualizing-survey-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and count the values:

```
print(df['answer'].str.split('; ').explode().value_counts().to_frame('Count').rename_axis('Answer'))
```

```
        Count
Answer       
A           3
C           3
B           2
```

Alternative using `collections.Counter` (as `explode` is not available in your version of Pandas):

```
from collections import Counter

res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(df['answer'].str.split('; ').agg(sum)), orient='index', columns=['Count']).rename_axis('Answer')
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, my pandas version is too low that it is said 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'.

Comment: @Sandy I updated my answer with an alternative. However, I highly suggest updating pandas if you can, since `explode` was introduced more than three years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `split` the semicolon column to list then explode at last `value_counts`

```py
out = (df.assign(answer=df['answer'].str.split('; '))
       .explode('answer')
       .value_counts('answer')
       .to_frame('Count')
       .reset_index()))
```

```
print(out)

  answer  Count
0      A      3
1      C      3
2      B      2
```

In case, `explode` is too new for your pandas, you can try `.apply(pd.Series).stack()` instead.

```py
out = (df['answer'].str.split('; ')
       .apply(pd.Series).stack()
       .value_counts()
       .to_frame('Count')
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'index': 'Answer'}))
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, my pandas version is too low that it is said 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'.